# unable to call exception block in oracle

Tags: oracle, exception, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have trying to execute below pl sql block in my oracle developer edition.I have made calls to functions and procedures and it works fines.But i am not able to call exception in case my query does not get executed.I have been trying to get a wrong query exectued by passing a string value instead of int value.So it throws error but also i need to get exception block to executed  in case of such error.Block 2 should through exception as i am passing string value.But exception block does not get call,Any help?? Below is my block

```
DECLARE  
  DBCID INT := 102;
  CNT INT;  
BEGIN  
  SELECT DEVOPS_ISDBCEXECUTED(DBCID, 'DDL') INTO CNT FROM DUAL;  
  IF (CNT = 0) THEN  
    BEGIN  
      DEVOPS_DBCINSERT (DBCID,'DDL','hsolanki','Prj1','Item1','avarne');
          BEGIN
            DECLARE W_CNT int;
            BEGIN
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO W_CNT FROM HS WHERE NAM = 'DK';   //block 1
                IF (W_CNT = 0) THEN 
                INSERT INTO HS
                  (NAM, AGE)
              VALUES    ('Dk',8);
                END IF;
            END;
          END;


          BEGIN
            DECLARE W_CNT int;
            BEGIN
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO W_CNT FROM HS WHERE NAM = 'Ab';
                IF (W_CNT = 0) THEN 
                INSERT INTO HS
                  (NAM, AGE)                     //block 2
              VALUES    ('Ab',s);
                END IF;
            END;
          END;
       DEVOPS_DBCUPDATE(DBCID, NULL,'SUCCESS');  
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('ERROR OCCURED : ' || sqlerrm); 
         DEVOPS_DBCUPDATE (DBCID,sqlerrm,'Failed');     
         rollback;
     END;           
  END IF;  
END;
```

Comment: Why so many nested blocks? It makes your code harder to understand without giving you anything back.

Comment: Also, `DEVOPS_DBCUPDATE` is presumably some form of logging or trace implementation. Does it write to a file or a table? If to a table, does it commit with `pragma autonomous_transaction` ?

Comment: DEVOPS_DBCUPDATE  is a procedure which updates a table

Comment: So when you say the exception block is "not executed" what does that mean? What evidence of execution are you looking for?

Comment: IN exception i am calling DEVOPS_DBCUPDATE (DBCID,sqlerrm,'Failed') which would update my table...my table is not getting updated

Comment: So I repeat my question: does DEVOPS_DBCUPDATE commit with `pragma autonomous_transaction`?

Comment: No i dont know what is pragma autonomous_transaction

Comment: If you update your table in the exception handling (DEVOPS_DBCUPDATE (DBCID,sqlerrm,'Failed');) and do not commit it (no autonomous trx either) and roll it back in the next statement, your update will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception handling block is within the 'IF (CNT = 0) THEN .. END IF' block. If you pass a string value, most probably the exception was thrown at the first function call ( SELECT DEVOPS_ISDBCEXECUTED...), which is not 'protected' by an excpetion handler. You would need to move the exception handler to the outermost block, e.g.:

```
DECLARE  
  DBCID INT := 102;
  CNT INT;  
BEGIN  
....
EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    ...
END;
```

Comment: That assignment still won't be caught as it is in the DECLARE section.

Comment: @TonyAndrews - The assignment error will be caught every time, since it's an anonymous pl/sql block (for this case in particular we have to change it to `DBCID INT := 'a102';`. If all this is put into a function or procedure in a package - it will be caught at the package initialization one time, then every consecutive time within the same session it won't. In all cases I think there's nothing wrong with initialization in standalone pl/sql blocks as such.

Comment: It won't be caught by your `WHEN OTHERS`, it will be raised as an unhandled Oracle "PL/SQL: numeric or value error".

Answer (score 1):

So we know ...

> DEVOPS_DBCUPDATE is a procedure which updates a table

... and ...

> IN exception i am calling DEVOPS_DBCUPDATE ... my table is not getting updated

... and ...

> i dont know what is pragma autonomous_transaction

Putting these clues altogether we can see that the `rollback` in the EXCEPTION block will wipe out the change to the table executed by the preceding call to `DEVOPS_DBCUPDATE()`, so it only *seems* as though the EXCEPTION block is not being executed ( a check on whether the `DBMS_OUTPUT` message is displayed would confirm that it is being called).

Anyway the solution is to make `DEVOPS_DBCUPDATE()` run in a nested transaction, so the change is applied regardless of what happens in the wider transaction. We do this with the  `autonomous_transaction` pragma.

Obviously I don't know the exact structure of your code, but it will look something like this:

```
create or replace procedure DEVOPS_DBCUPDATE( ... ) is
    pragma  autonomous_transaction;
begin
    update your_table
    set ....
    commit; 
end;
```

The COMMIT in the procedure will persist the change to your table but will not save anything in the outer transaction. So the `rollback` in the EXCEPTION block would still reverse the inserts into the `HS` table.

Autonomous transactions are very useful when employed properly, but it is easy to misuse them. This scenario - persistent logging in the event of exception or rollback - is their main use case. But generally, use with caution: it's easy to abuse autonomous transactions and end up with a corrupted database. There's more information [in the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS00609).

Answer (score 0):

An error raise in the `DECLARE` section is not handled by that block's `EXCEPTION` section.  For this reason it is often safer to initialise variables after the `BEGIN` i.e.

```
DECLARE  
  DBCID INT;
  CNT INT;  
BEGIN  
  DBCID := 'xxx';
  ...
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
     ... -- The assignment will be caught here
END;
```